# Median_filter in python

Tags: python

Please help me with this problem. I use median_filter with an input matrix 5x5, and a kernel 3x3 and i want my output matrix size is 5x5. There are 2 cases with the input matrix. In case 2, I use zero-padding to the matrix and the result is different.

Comment: What is your question? Is the output matrix not 5x5? What shape is it then? What is your kernel stride?

Comment: This is my first time using stackover flow =((. My input matrix size is 5x5, and my kernel_size is 3x3. I want my output matrix is 5x5, so the input matrix, i use zero-padding to ensure it will return the output matrix 5x5.

Comment: Here's my code:
def apply_median_filter(input_matrix, kernel_size):
    output_matrix = median_filter(input_matrix,size=kernel_size)
    return output_matrix

Comment: # Case 1:
input_matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                         [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                         [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                         [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
                         [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
kernel_size = (3,3)
output_matrix = apply_median_filter(input_matrix,filter_matrix)

# Output 1:
[[ 2  3  4  5  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10]
 [11 12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19 20]
 [21 21 22 23 24]]

--> That's irrelevant. If it's correct, can anybody explain it to me ....

Comment: # Case 2:
input_matrix = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0],
                         [0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0],
                         [0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0],
                         [0, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 0],
                         [0, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 0],
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
# Output 2:
[[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  2  3  4  0  0]
 [ 0  2  7  8  9  5  0]
 [ 0  7 12 13 14 10  0]
 [ 0 12 17 18 19 15  0]
 [ 0  0 17 18 19  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
The same answer when I solve mannually

Comment: Case 2 return the correct answer when i have to add zero-adding into the input matrix and case 1 return the wrong answer. I think the median_filter in scipy_ndimage will add zero-padding automatically when i type the input matrix

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result. **Do not put these examples in the comments!**

Comment: Reading the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.median_filter.html) on SciPy's median filter, it clearly states that the output shape is the same as the input, even providing the ways you can handle the edges.